# How to best precache videos in webview/mobile browser on Android/iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, webview

## Description

With the fast approaching removal of **synchronous** `XMLHttpRequest` (i.e.: Chrome 88 is removing this), I am looking for the next optimal alternative method to precache a video.

> "Sychronous XMLHttpRequest is a horrible idea" -
> said no one ever

Yes, you're right for *most* scenarios but this is different.

## Previously

On [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [ios](/questions/tagged/ios), the company I work for has an SDK that opens a [webview](/questions/tagged/webview) in the background, injects HTML into it and waits for the `onload` event to fire. This notifies the SDK when the webview is ready to be shown to the user.

It is **imperative** that when a video plays there is **NO** buffering whatsoever for the best possible experience.

This is *why* when the webview is loading in the background, we precache the video [synchronously with XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) (which by consequence, delays the `onload` event from being fired).

## Possible solutions

*We've thought about some different solutions, and they each have their pros and cons; here are a few:*

1. [Preload content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) via `<link rel="preload" ... />`
2. Embed the video within the `index.html` page in base64 (if the video weights 2-3Mo, it'll weigh 30% more after converting to base64)

(1) is the cleanest method, but requires some *heavy* changes on our backend for various reasons. There is also no guarantee that the video will be fully cached by the time the browser/webview appears. There is no guarantee that the priority of the precaching will be the same across webviews and mobile browsers. Users can deactivate the precaching features, for example, in their Chrome configuration. It also does not work when the connection is 4G or lower (*sigh*).

(2) is a hacky and unoptimized method but is *relatively* simple to implement compared to (1)

## Question

What is the next best method to precache a video in the background of a webview/mobile browser that:

1. Guarantees (or closely guarantees) no buffering when the video is played
2. Is done within webview/browser
3. Is (preferably) cross mobile browser/webview compatible
4. (preferably and not required) delays the `onload` event from being triggered

*Note: not all users may have a 4g or wifi connection.*
*Note2:  tag is in autoplay*

Comment: Could you place the video somewhere hidden in the DOM and let it start loading asynchronously, and use a timer to check if it's buffered before loading the webview?

Comment: @joshstrike you could but it won't work. I've tried having a long sync loop while the video would load asynchronously.. and have the video onloadeddata stop the sync loop. Wasn't successful, but hey if you get it to work please let me know.

Comment: How are you playing the video currently, i think you should include the code that is relevant for playing the video in the question. The code for doing the xml html request, and how the video is injected in html and using what html tags

Comment: @ehab the code is irrelevant as it's becoming completely deprecated and I'm looking for a completely new strategy.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't fetch the video first then when it's fetched open the webview and inject html?

Comment: @AhmedMokhtar yes it's totally possible to do it this way and it's something we've thought about but the complexity of doing that compared to finding a solution with the current existing system is much more important.

Answer (score 2):

To guarantee that there is no buffering when the video is played, the video can first be downloaded as a `blob` using the native `fetch` API and then converted to objectURL using `window.URL.createObjectURL`. This URL can then be used as the source for video element

This is a native API built-in the webview/browser and the compatibility report can be found here [Can I use fetch](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)

And instead of listening for `onload` event, listen for some other custom made event which you can manually control. This will give better flexibility in future also.

```
  <script>

      fetch('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4').then(response => {
          //Video Download Started
          return response.blob();

      }).then(data => {
          //Video Downloaded"
          let objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
          document.querySelector("#myvideoPlayer").src = objectUrl;

          //Trigger a custom event here
      }).catch(error => {
          // Log Error
      })

  </script>

  <video controls id="myvideoPlayer"></video>
```

Comment: `fetch` is asynchronous and it cannot delay the `onload` event so there is no guarantee that the video is loaded. Unfortunately, I *must* use `onload`. It's part of the industry standard and there would be compatibility issues with other company SDKs. Also, It won't be compatible with our old SDKs that are being used by other developers. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That being said, interesting idea. I also think that specific method may become [obselete in the future](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Using_object_URLs_for_media_streams).

Comment: Please note that the usage of `createObjectURL` is deprecated only for `MediaStream` objects, not `Blob` or `MediaSource` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The new solution is by using the [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)

```
caches = window.caches;
caches.open("app-assets").then((cache) => {
  cache.add(linkToFileToBeCached).then(() => {
    // Now the file is cached. Start rendering the app!
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm confused as how this is supposed to solve the problem?

Comment: What are you confused about? it's an awesome JavaScript API that you can use to programmatically pre-cache any resources and it's supported on all browsers except Internet Explorer

Comment: This does not solve the issue in my situation and does not guarantee that the video will be remotely ready when the webview comes to the foreground. It is a solution for a different scenario.

Comment: I did read the documentation. This puts the video in the cache of the browser asynchronously to be used and reused. I just want to precache (load the video ahead of time before the webview appears) and then show it once to the user. How does this ensure that when the webview appears that the video will be able to immediately (auto) play through without any buffering?

Comment: it returns a Promise. You can write code to wait until the Promise is resolved while temporarily displaying any loading screen.. and you can even start loading all your assets once the user installs the app so the user wouldn't even have to wait for a loading screen when opening the video.

Comment: There cannot be any loading screens. I work in the mobile ad business. Would be catastrophic for the business if there was a loading screen before a video could play.

Comment: The video will definitely take time to download anyway. If you don't want to display a loading page, you can load it much earlier, long before the user opens the video

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading an html page - use preload="auto" in the video tag.  This tells the browser to download the entire video on page load (the default is preload = "metadata" which downloads 3-5% of the video).

You can then look at the mediaEvent `canPlayThrough` to fire to know when the video is ready to play([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)).

Have you thought about streaming the video?  A properly configured stream should begin playback immediately, and have little to no buffering as the adaptive bitrate algorithm can change the video delivered based on the device screen AND network throughput.  [api.video](https://api.video) has a great service (with SDKs for iOS, Android and several web backends)